# Substituting values in a HTML table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django, django-simple-history

I am making a HTML table to display boxes (in a stockroom) that have been added, removed and changed. The headings are denoting the owner of the box, the type of change that has occurred and the new content of the box.

Im using Django for my backend.

Can I translate the values in the 'Type of Change' into English words rather than the symbols (~, - and +)? I am using Django simple-history to record changes to my models and it returns these symbols. I would like my table to read 'Changed', 'Removed' and 'Added' in place of '~', '-' and '+' respectfully.

[image: My table]

This is the view.py:

```
def dashboard(request):
    box_content_history = Box.history.all().order_by('-history_date')
    return render(request, 'main_app/dashboard.html', {""box_content_history":box_content_history})
```

The HTML:

```
<table id="asset_changes_datatable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Owner</th>
            <th>Type of Change</th>
            <th>Box Contents</th>
        </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
   {% for item in box_content_history %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ item.project_assigned_to }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.history_type }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.box_contents }}</td>
        </tr>
   {% endfor %}
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Edited to correct ordering of terms

Comment: Can you show the view/template code that's responsible for rendering the `~`/`-`/`+` symbols?

Comment: I have just done that now

Comment: Please try if changing `{{ item.history_type }}` to `{{ item.get_history_type_display }}` does what you are trying to achieve. If it does I will provide a more thorough answer explaining it.

Comment: It does work! Thank you! Thats amazing! Is this some kind of built in method in simple-history?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comments just change `{{ item.history_type }}` to `{{ item.get_history_type_display }}` in the template.

#### What is this sorcery and where does it come from?

This is actually vanilla django functionality and is explained in the [Model instance reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_FOO_display).

> For every field that has **[choices](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.choices)** set, the object will have a **get_FOO_display()** method, where **FOO** is the name of the field. This method returns the “human-readable” value of the field.

#### Why does it work for the `history_type` field of django-simple-history?

Quite simple: The `history_type` field has the aforementioned **`choices`** set. I checked that by looking at [their source](https://github.com/treyhunner/django-simple-history/blob/2e89360d2c95d9bff66837a686db77d45d299a0a/simple_history/models.py#L331) code on github.

> ```
> "history_type": models.CharField(
>     max_length=1,
>     choices=(("+", _("Created")), ("~", _("Changed")), ("-", _("Deleted"))),
> ),
> ```

Comment: Thats fantastic. Its so helpful that these "human readable" values have been defined in models! Thank you for your answer!